# Encouraging Small Bounties

Tags: discussion, bounties

Is there a way that we can encourage users to post small bounties on their questions (to encourage good and numerous answers)?

It occured to me that selecting an answer awards the OP a small amount of rep, so if we could find a way to encourage the OP to offer a similar amount as a bounty, we may see an increase in the number of answers posted.

Any thoughts on how we may promote this?

Comment: Bounty of 2 rep is just a joke.

Comment: How small are we talking here? If you mean <10, then I agree with @ShadowWizard. That can be a lot for a new user, but it's just the equivalent of an extra upvote.

Comment: Well that's why I left it as 'small' rather than giving a figure.

Comment: It was more to encourage people posting bounties of 10-15 rep (easily recoverable for a good question with up votes). It may help get new sign ups involved in answering as well as just asking (the reason most sign up is because they have a question in mind)

Answer (score 13):

If you did this, there would be *no point* of having bounties - because *every user* would start a bounty on their questions.

The 'featured' list would be extremely full - your attempt to get more attention would probably backfire because nobody will see that question. So it would be *harmful* to encourage users to do something that isn't (and shouldn't) be possible.

The entire point of having bounties is that you give a bit of your rep for more attention, and *to reward users for their answers*.

Putting a small bounty on would tell potential answerers you don't really care about the question much - you can't 'afford' to start a slightly higher bounty to get a high quality answer. Personally, I wouldn't answer a question to get an extra 15 (?) rep - because the asker wouldn't think the answer is going to be worth a bit if rep. After all, rep is a bonus - it feels nice to get some rep.

Besides, what's the difference between 10 rep (for an answer upvote) and something less than 50 rep (the current minimum bounty amount)? Hardly anything. So I honestly don't think there's any point trying to encourage users.

Answer (score 5):

[An upvote on a question is worth +5 rep. An upvote on an answer is worth +10 rep.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238)

[By comparison, the lowest bounty that can be set is 50 rep, and the lowest amount a person can receive is 25 rep (if the bounty is auto-awarded).](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067)

Looking at the comparison there, low-end bounties aren't too big. If you make some smaller, there's less incentive.

Plus, bounty-worthy answers usually get a lot of upvotes, so a bounty of, say, 10, is only the equivalent of an extra upvote. That's not a huge motivator.

Comment: Problem is bounties especially on new SEs are pretty rare. Allowing and encouraging smaller bounties on good questions would encourage better and more answers

Comment: @Malekai I don't think that bounties that small will be motivating enough, as I wrote.

Comment: Maybe not to established SEs for people with thousands of rep but to new SEs with a young community then it would help

Comment: @Malekai I still disagree. Why would motivations be any different?

Comment: Because to someone with say 100 rep a bounty of 25 isn't bad. To someone with 50,000 then I agree, pointless

Comment: Sure, but *in comparison with answer upvotes* - as I said - there's no advantage.